# Using EF Code First can I delete my development dbs and migration folder and just start again?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have set up my mvc project and in my localdb/MSSQLLocaldb there are two databases - the defaultconnection for the identity AspNet tables and the database for my project (the db is called BeforeDb). I have updated some of the tables and run migrations.

But I just watched Scott Allens tutorial https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&mode=live&clip=3&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

And in that it is a much more elegant solution than mine. So my question is can i delete my db and the migrations folder and the migration history table and implement the way Scott has and build my solution again? One of my questions is whether there is migration info hiding in config files, etc. that i also would need to delete or is all the migration details in the migration history table and folder.

Regards

Comment: Yes, assuming you don't want any existing data. Your database will be rebuilt based on the models and fluent code. If you have seeding code you may want to back that up.

Comment: Thanks. So rather than using migrations if my database data in development isn't particularly important i can just delete the database, add properties to my models and then rebuild my solution. Is that correct? And if that's the case why migrations to start with? EF can build a database from the models using the code first approach so it kind of suprises me that it can't just igure out that i might have added another property to a model and just add a column to the db. Cheers.

Comment: I only implement migrations when I hit a point where I need to keep data that is not seeded. You can work with DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges and have it seed the minimal needed logins and lookup data. See https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: When you are ready to switch to migrations, you can add an initial baseline so only subsequent changes are tracked: `add-migration MyBaseline -IgnoreChanges` then change the initializer to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`

Comment: Thanks. That's great.